# LSTM - sentence completion with word2vec

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm, prediction, word2vec

I want to create a model that can predict a word missing in a sentence (the sentence has a whole which needs to be filled)

My dataset consists of ~1000 sentences, shortest sentence is length=6, longest sentence is length~120000. The vocabulary size of the dataset is only 90.

Would it make a huge difference for the model to have either onehot-encoding or a pre-trained word2vec (gensim) model? I use the pre-trained weights in a keras embedding layer: what would be the sense of "freezing" (not trainable) that layer as it did not make any difference regarding the accuracy in my case?

I tried both representation and there seems to be no difference regarding the accuracy of my test data. The highest accuracy I achieved was 55% correctly predicted.

Am I on the right track or is it the wrong approach to do that task? My machine is very slow which makes experiments with parameters so hard and time consuming.

I would be grateful for any advice or tip!

Answer (score 1):

*Would it make a difference?* Yes, of course but only to the extent of the 90 words you have in your vocabulary. The advantage of using word2vec with freezing is that your model can fill sentences with words it has seen before but might be *similar* to what it was trained on.

*What would be sense of freezing?* Word2vec was trained on millions of tokens but you only have 90 of them in your dataset. So if you don't freeze your model will only modify the 90 words which might lose their relationship to other words. For example if you have *television* but not *TV* then the meaning of *television* might change with respect to *TV* depending on your dataset.